# splice method only once

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a stepper inside my application when user selects specific options on first step i want to splice some steps from my step array, but i have splice function on button, so everytime i go back and click button again it splices another item, how can i make it splice only once?
here is my array of steps:

**.ts**

```
this.stepService.steps = [
  FirstStep,
  SecondStep,
  ThirdStep,
  FourthStep,
  SuccessPageComponent
];

nextStep() {

    let value = { ...this.form.value };
         if (value.type == 'once') {
          this.stepService.steps.splice(2, 1);
        }
    
        if (value.type == 'multiple') {
          this.stepService.steps.splice(1, 1);
        }

}
```

Comment: You mean this `nextStep()` should be called only once?

Comment: Hi! yes i mean that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `slice()` instead.

`splice()` changes the original array, `slice()` doesn't but both of them returns array object.

Comment: Hi! thanks for the answer but how can i slice only second (SecondStep) element from my array?

Comment: can you explain more? I didn't get what you are asking. @GalathyniusAelin

Comment: i want to remove second element from my array (SecondStep element), how can i do that with slice()?